# How to create subsets of an RDD with column wise splitting in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large dataset as one RDD. I want to create about 100 column wise subsets of this RDD, so that I am able to run a map transformation on a each subset separately in a loop.

My RDD looks for example like this:

```
(1,2,3,...,1000)
(1,2,3,...,1000)
(1,2,3,...,1000)
```

I want a column wise split, for example 10 splits, so one subset should look like this:

```
(1,2,3,...,100)
(1,2,3,...,100)
(1,2,3,...,100)
```

How can i do that in Pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use range and loop:

```
for i in range(0, 1000, 100):
    rdd.map(lambda row: row[i:i + 100]).someOtherOperation(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is there a way to do that with sparse dataset (libsvm)? I get an error, when i do that or is there a way to convert to dense so i can use the loop.